# Can I use Firebase Management API without gRPC?

Tags: firebase, rest, retrofit, grpc

I'm trying to write a small code to make some configurations on firebase automatic.
The first step was create a new project on Google Cloud Platform using the API. This step is ok!

Now I need to create a firebase for this same project using the API.

I'm confortable with making requests using RETROFIT, so I use REST. It happens the endpoint for creating a new firebase project uses something called "gRPC".

The endpoint for creating new firebase project is:

```
https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{project=projects/*}:addFirebase
```

I've already tried to replace "projects" with my project id, but I get 404 from server.

My question is: is there a way to "translate" this gRPC request to a REST endpoint? Something that I can use @PATH or @QUERY?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for this API here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase

It is a plain-ole REST API

You will need to specify the value for `project` as `projects/[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]`

I recommend you try it out using APIs Explorer ("Try this API") on the right hand side of the documentation page to confirm that it works for you.